# Store key that has duplicate value into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary and want to store the name of the keys that have the same first three letters for its value. For example:

```
dictionary = {'apple': 'ams2.dfgsdfgsdfg', 'orange': 'bru1.asdfartq', 'grape': 'cph.dfsdfgsdgsdf', 'banana': 'ams4.ewrtwerth'
```

Since I want the output to print the list of keys with duplicate values(look at first 3 letters), the final output would print a list like this:

```
list = ['apple', 'banana']
```

If anyone could help this **rookie** by creating the code, much would be appreciated!

Comment: downvoted since there was no attempt at an answer. Being a rookie is ok, but before asking for help at least read the guidelines and try yourself.

Comment: @Skirrebattie sorry, I attempted it but didn't attach. Ill make sure to include it next time! Thanks!

Comment: Loop through `for k, v in dictionary.items():`.  Build a new dictionary mapping `v[:3]` to a list of all the keys that have values that begin with those characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution avoids looping through every element of the dictionary for each element, because that doesn't perform well:

The first step is to sort the data using the **key** you want - in your example the key is the first 3 chars of the value.

```
def key_first3(element):
    return element[1][:3]
data = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=key_first3)
```

Now, you can group the data using this key, and count the number of elements in the group. If a group has more than one element, add its keys to the result:

```
result = []

for key, group in itertools.groupby(data, key=key_first3):
    group = list(group)
    if len(group) > 1:
         result.append(tuple(k for k, v in group))
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt:

```
dictionary = {'apple': 'ams2.dfgsdfgsdfg', 'orange': 'bru1.asdfartq', 'grape': 'cph.dfsdfgsdgsdf', 'banana': 'ams4.ewrtwerth'}

duplicate_keys = set()
for k1, v1 in dictionary.items():
    for k2, v2 in dictionary.items():
        if k1 == k2:
            continue
        if v1[:3] == v2[:3]:
            duplicate_keys.add(k1)
            duplicate_keys.add(k2)
print(list(duplicate_keys))
```

Outputs:

```
['apple', 'banana']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> d = {'apple': 'ams2.dfgsdfgsdfg', 'orange': 'bru1.asdfartq', 'grape': 'cph.dfsdfgsdgsdf', 'banana': 'ams4.ewrtwerth'}
>>> f = key=lambda x: x[1][:3]
>>> grouped_d = {k:list(dict(v).keys()) for k,v in groupby(sorted(d.items(), key=f), f)}
>>> grouped_d
{'ams': ['apple', 'banana'], 'bru': ['orange'], 'cph': ['grape']}
>>> [v for k,v in grouped_d.items() if len(v)>1]
[['apple', 'banana']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to capture the 3 letters in the beginning of the items that are similar. Then use list comprehension to find the keys for the items with the similar 3 words. Decided to use `zip`. Just realized dictionary no longer has the attribute `iteritems()`. Cant tell why

```
import re

 a = "".join(re.findall(r"(\b\w{3}).*?\1"," ".join(dictionary.values())))    
     [m for m,x in zip(dictionary,dictionary.values()) if a in x]

 ['apple', 'banana']
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.